# How do I connect a curve of fixed length between two points in space using Matlab?

Tags: matlab

We have two points (x1,y1,z1) and (x2,y2,z2) in 3d space. We have a curve of **fixed length** which is to be connected (not with a straight line) between these points. How to proceed with the code in Matlab?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense to me... what do you mean by connecting a curve between two points?

Comment: We are actually planning a Path between start and goal points for deformable linear objects (Snake like robots). The above mentioned two are the start and goal configurations and we have to plan the path between these points. The length of the snake like robot is fixed.

Comment: What if they two points are exactly or more than the specified length?  Technically, a line is a type of curve.  Furthermore, there are hundreds if not thousands of curve types.  Which one would you like?

Comment: We want minimal energy curves between start and goal points. We plan the path within a fixed volume and the curve length is always greater than the diagonal sqrt(x^2+y^2+z^2) of the cuboid so that the points cannot be connected by a straight line.

Comment: Your question is rather vague. It would help if you could add more detail, specifically an example of whatever code you may have already started writing.

Comment: Vinodh, we really need more information.  What other constraints do you have?  Without other constraints, there are uncountably many such curves in R^3.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing how far you've gotten trying to use snakes (i.e. active contours), the best I can do is suggest these links:

- [Active Contours, Deformable Models, and Gradient Vector Flow](http://iacl.ece.jhu.edu/projects/gvf/).
- Some active-contour modeling by [Bregler and Slaney](http://cobweb.ecn.purdue.edu/~malcolm/interval/1995-017/).
- [Active Contour Segmentation](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/19567) by Shawn Lankton.
- [Active Contour Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/11643) by Eric Debreuve.

Most applications of active contours I've come across appear to be more for 2-D image segmentation, but hopefully these links will give you some jumping off points.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to minimize the bend angles at your robot's joints, then the best curve would be a circular arc.

Let L be the length of the arc, d be the distance between the endpoints, theta be *half* the angle of the arc, and r be the radius of the arc. Then:

d/L = sin(theta)/theta   ==> solve this numerically for theta using one of Matlab's solvers

Once you have theta, the radius of the arc is: r = L / (2 * theta)

There are still an infinite number of arcs between the two endpoints with this r and theta. You'll have to use some other criteria to select what roll angle about the points to use.

Comment: Would this curve still work if L is greater than pi*d/2 (i.e. if L is greater than half of the circumference of a circle of diameter d)?

Comment: Yes, it should work for all distance / arc length ratios between (but not including) 1 and 0.